# Redirect to link via workflow button click

Tags: javascript, workflow, netsuite

I have added a button via workflow and I need to redirect it to another location/link(say ..  www.google.com link). How can I achive this, Since button's id cannot be changed in workflow, I could not append any Javascript function in that button . Also Action in workflow does not have an option to set link to Workflow buttons,.
Does this mean Workflow buttons can only be made to move to another State?

Note: I know to add buttons via user script but for this particular scenario I want to achive this only with workflow button.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to handle button clicks in workflows is to create a transition to another state. Within the transition, there is a drop-down field called Button that lets you choose which button would fire the transition.

You can only cause a workflow to navigate to either a record using the `Go To Record action`, or a task link using the `Go To Page` action. But I'm not sure if you could navigate to a link using workflows as you've mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a button and hijack it via a client script? Just add a call on the form of client side to find the button element on the DOM and change the properties. This can be easily done with jQuery, which comes by default on NetSuite.